# How to provide dimens values for xhdpi and above?

Tags: android, android-layout

Is it possible to give one set of dimen values for `xhdpi` and above densities and another set of dimen values for `hdpi` and below densities in android? I have been trying to accomplish this by creating one `values-xhdpi` folder for `xhdpi` and above densities and keeping `values` folder for other densities.

Is this approach correct, because I am not getting expected results. If no then what is the right approach to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your approach is partially correct according to https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#support

> If no matching resource is available, the system uses the default resource and scales it up or down as needed to match the current screen size and density

That means if you will have for example `xxhdpi` screen, system will pick resources from `xhdpi` folder.

But if you want to use `hdpi` resources for all the below density screens, you should provide values-hdpi rather than just `values`.

You can find this quote in the documentation:

> The system assumes that default resources (those from a directory without configuration qualifiers) are designed for the baseline screen density (`mdpi`), unless they are loaded from a density-specific resource directory.

So there is no guaranty that system will pick your resources from `values` folder for `hdpi` screen.